# React-native: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cb.apply')

Tags: debugging, react-native

I don't know where to start to debug this error, it showed up in my simulator out of no where. The error lines numbers don't correlate with any code that I have written (from the start to finish of the call stack). Anyone have any ideas what this error means?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code causing this?